# Uploading and listing files from a sharable google drive link with Pydrive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I have searched through the API's but haven't been able to find a way to upload files and download files(list files) pragmatically to a shared folder (and not my own google drive). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manage files from public Google Drive URL using PyDrive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913458/manage-files-from-public-google-drive-url-using-pydrive)

Comment: Thanks, let me check if that works.

Comment: Did you get it to work?